# collision between two sprites

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit

Im trying to get collision between two sprites but it doesn't work they hit and not contact is detected.

> In GameScene.h

```
@interface GameScene : SKScene <SKPhysicsContactDelegate>{
```

*

> In GameScene.m

```
static const uint32_t ballCategory = 1<<0;
static const uint32_t obs1Category = 1<<1;
```

*

```
ball = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"ball_cross"];
ball.position = CGPointMake(bx,by);
ball.name = @"ball";
ball.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:ball.size];
ball.physicsBody.dynamic = YES;
ball.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = ballCategory;
ball.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = obs1Category;
ball.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = obs1Category;
```

*

```
obs1 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"obs1"];
obs1.position = obs1XY;
obs1.name = @"obs1";
obs1.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:obs1.size];
obs1.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = obs1Category;
obs1.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = ballCategory;
obs1.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = ballCategory;
obs1.physicsBody.dynamic = YES;
```

*

```
-(void)didBeginContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact{

   NSLog(@"hit");
}
```

Comment: Put the Physics Delegate into your implementation file.

Comment: Will that do anything ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the collision bit mask and contact test bit masks you need to add the two bodies you want to receive notifications from.

IE:

```html
obs1.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = obs1Category;
obs1.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = ballCategory;
obs1.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = ballCategory || obs1Category;

ball.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = ballCategory;
ball.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = obs1Category || ballCategory;
ball.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = obs1Category;
```

Son when the contact bit mask matched the combination between ball and orbs a notification will be generated.

I hope this helps mate!